# Fast way to compare a string with an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array with a lot of names: `{'John Doe', 'Peter Shark', ...}`.

Now I would like to compare and match a string for e.g. `'This is your turn John Doe, pls do it'` and return the **name(s)**, if the array contains it.
The string could be a long text.

I´ve tried it like this, but it do not work:

```
var searchStr = "This is your turn John Doe, pls do it"

var stringArray = ["John Doe", "Peter Shark"];

return (stringArray.indexOf(searchStr) > -1)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to search the other way around - iterate over `stringArray` and check if `some` of the names are contained in `searchStr`:

```js
var searchStr1 = "This is your turn John Doe, pls do it";
var stringArray = ["John Doe", "Peter Shark"];
console.log(stringArray.some(name => searchStr1.includes(name)));

var searchStr2 = "This is your turn Foo Bar, pls do it";
console.log(stringArray.some(name => searchStr2.includes(name)));
```

While `some` is very clean and clear, `for` loops are slightly faster than array methods, though it should only matter if you have tens of thousands of items to iterate over:

```js
var searchStr = "This is your turn John Doe, pls do it";
var stringArray = ["John Doe", "Peter Shark"];

const searchFor = stringArray => {
  for (let i = 0, { length } = stringArray; i < length; i++) {
    if (searchStr.includes(stringArray[i])) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

console.log(searchFor(["John Doe", "Peter Shark"]));
console.log(searchFor(["Foo Bar", "Peter Shark"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are pretty good at finding stuff quick. You can prepare the regexp ahead of time, then just reuse it later, if your `stringArray` stays the same:

```js
let searchStr = "This is your turn John Doe, pls do it"
let stringArray = ["John Doe", "Peter Shark"];

let nameMatcher = new RegExp(stringArray.map(
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript
  s => s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
).join('|'));

console.log(searchStr.match(nameMatcher));
```